# What is the real structure of a pointer?

Tags: pointers, types

As I have so far learnt, a pointer is a place in memory (heap) where a memory address is stored, I really understand that and can deal with it so easily, but the question is : if it only stores an address, then it's size is symmetric with the size of the memory of the computer, **and so all pointers have the same size**, then why pointers have types, if a pointer X is defined integer for example, it has the same size as the poiter Y which is defined char, why is there a compiler or runtime error when I assign an address of double - or any type diffrenet from integer - to X, and the same for Y? is there any additional component in the structure of pointers which determines the type?

I just want to know the real structure of pointers, how exactly they work, and why they have types.

Thanks in advance :)

NOTE : if I have to specify a language, it's C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, a pointer just contains a memory address, and so all the pointers on a given machine have exactly the same size.

**The type and the corresponding compiler errors are here to help you make some consistent code**. But once the code is compiled, nothing in the memory structure of the pointer can tell anything about its type.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the real structure of pointers ( I liked the idea so I'll have a look on the topic I think you can find something about it in automata theory and programming languages design or in writing compilers topics ) but I think pointers have data types so the computer know how much of memory does the pointer points at, in other words consider a pointer that points to a double, I think the pointer points on the address of the first word of the size that the double takes, but consider you want to output the double on the screen, if the pointer didn't have type that is consistent with the value it points at, how would the computer know how many bytes should it print on the screen!.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer when initialized points to the first byte of the data to which it points. For example, if a int pointer is pointing to data e.g. 45 then pointer may be point to value 4 or 5 (depending upon the end-inaness of the machine). In the similar manner, a double pointer will be pointing to the first byte in memory of the data to which it is pointing.

So this way all the pointers have same size.

Now, according to the type of the pointer, data from memory is accessed. So on 16 bit computer where int is 16 bit, two byte data is referenced (including the starting byte from memory to which pointer is pointing and the next immediate byte) from memory when this pointer is dereferenced. In similar manner a 4 bytes will be referenced when a long pointer is dereferenced.

This is how in general pointer dereferencing in general works. So in short, pointers have type to dereference the data correctly. And all the pointers essentially have same size i.e. 1 byte. Hope I am enough clear.

Answer (score -1):

I thought a pointer was stored on the stack and it pointed to a location on the heap?

Pointers have 'types' just like variables to provide type safety and allow you to pick up problems at compile time. But note this is only at compile time (in C anyway).

In reality you can via code set the pointer to any memory location and this is what causes many problems in code and vulnerablities that viruses exploit. Walking along an array using a pointer is a common trick but this does allow a pointer to walk beyond the end of the array and access and modify parts of the memory that you weren't expecting.

Comment: A pointer is just a value that the compiler will interpret as an address . It can be stored on the heap, on the stack, or merely transiently in registers. And you don't need pointers to have the possibility of walking off the end of an array, you can just as easily do this with indices.